# How to change the shortcut of “Show or hide the definition of the selected word” in Mac OS?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

As stated on [this](https://support.apple.com/en-la/HT201236) Apple's support page, there is a <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut to "Show or hide the definition of the selected word" in documents.

I really love this keyboard shortcut but <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is hard to press.
And I can't find it in `System Preference > Keyboard > Shortcuts`, therefore I can't change this shortcut.

Is there any other way to change it?

Comment: Good question, I have the same issue as yours.